# Power analysis to detect non-zero skew/kurtosis

Tags: statistical-power, skewness, kurtosis

Tests exist to determine whether a distribution is normal. For example the Shapiro-Wilk’s method. I'm wondering how to determine whether I'm powered to detect that my distribution is non-normal (e.g., null hypothesis is that skew is 0, alternative is that it is different from 0). I could of course run a simulation - I'm specifically interested in an *analytic* power analyses.

Here is an example where my sample is too small (underpowered) to detect a significant effect, even though the population is skewed (the data is drawn from a gamma distribution with a skew of 2):

```
> set.seed(123)
> dat = rgamma(10,shape = 1)
> shapiro.test(dat)

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  dat
W = 0.94299, p-value = 0.5867
```

What sample size would I need to have 80% power to find a significant effect?

Comment: Not a great test.  Why not use one of the better ones, such as Shapiro-Wilk and its relatives?  At any rate, to run a power analysis you need to propose a set of alternative distributions or at least define a suitable effect size.  Since you want some analysis, please tell us what your alternative is.

Comment: Thanks @whuber! I've made some edits - I'm not particularly interested in the specific test, though I know it matters. I'm wondering if *any* such analytic power analysis exists.

Comment: **1**. "Tests exist to determine whether a distribution is normal." ... no, there are no tests that will tell you that the population distribution *is* normal. Some tests may be able to detect that it isn't normal, or it may fail to detect that. **2**. Power depends on how non-normal it is (in some specific way -- you may need to specify the distribution under the alternative, at least up to location and scale to engage in comparisons of power). Power also depends on sample size and significance level, of course.

Comment: You're beginning to get there, but "skew is not zero" still leaves far too many alternatives to explore.  When people study these tests, they propose various parametric families believed to be characteristic of the situations researchers might face with a range of skewnesses.  For instance, you might let your alternative hypothesis consist of all uniform, exponential, gamma, or lognormal distributions, then study the power of the test against each one of these alternative formulations.

Comment: Would a test against a skew-normal distribution be of interest?